# How to find length of string without using len() and for,while loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just picked up Python, and I really need some help with this **Homework** question(don't kill me please). So, I have already wrote this, however, I want to make it recursive, but I don't know what's wrong with this. I thought that the code would just repeat itself, but apparently I have made a mistake somewhere.

```
def count_length(string):
    x = 0
    if string[x:]=="":
        return x
    else:
        x += 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not recursion because you are calling the function again.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def count_length(string, clen=0):
    try:
        string[clen]
        return count_length(string, clen+1)
    except:
        return clen

print count_length('ABCDE') ----> 5
```